# Php front controller works with errors

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, routes

I'm trying to make simple routing with php using apache. This is my .htaccess file:
`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

'

This is my index.php :

```
<?php

  echo "request = " . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Also i got test.php in directory.As far as i understand it should redirect all requests that is not an existent files ot folders. All works fine for random request and works directly for `localhost\test.php`.  But once i try `localhost\test`  or `localhost\test\new` It doesnt get redirected to the index.php.  `The requested URL /test/new was not found on this server`. What do i miss?

And there is my apache settings:

```
<Directory /var/www/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Put something like `qpweorwer` in a new line in your `.htaccess` (and make sure it's spelled right - `.htacsess` is not correct) to make sure it's having an effect - an invalid `.htaccess` should cause a 500 error. If it doesn't, it's not being read at all.

Comment: Thank you for correction, my original named right, and it having effect since most of urls are redirecting except this examples here.

Comment: Do you have an actual folder called `test` that could be overriding this?

Comment: @ceejayoz No, there are no more folders in my root. `  /var/www/public$ ls
index.php  new.php  test.php `